# IWebBrowser: How to specify the encoding when loading html from a stream?

Tags: encoding, mshtml, istream, iwebbrowser2

Using the concepts from the [sample code provided by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752047(VS.85).aspx) for loading HTML content into an [IWebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127(VS.85).aspx) from an [IStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380034(VS.85).aspx) using the web browser's [IPersistStreamInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682273(VS.85).aspx) interface:

### pseudocode:

```
void LoadWebBrowserFromStream(IWebBrowser webBrowser, IStream stream)
{
   IPersistStreamInit persist = webBrowser.Document as IPersistStreamInit;
   persist.Load(stream);
}
```

How can one specify the encoding of the html inside the IStream? The IStream will contain a series of bytes, but the problem is what do those bytes represent? They could, for example, contain bytes where:

- each byte represents a character from the current Windows code-page (e.g. 1252)
- each byte could represent a character from the ISO-8859-1 character set
- the bytes could represent UTF-8 encoded characters
- every 2 bytes could represent a character, using UTF-16 encoding

In my particular case, i am providing the IWebBrowser an IStream that contains a series of double-bytes characters (UTF-16), but the browser (incorrectly) believes that UTF-8 encoding is in effect. This results in garbled characters.

### Workaround solution

While the question asks how to specify the encoding, in my particular case, with only UTF-16 encoding, there's a simple workaround. Adding the 0xFEFF Byte Order Mark (BOM) indicates that the text is UTF-16 unicode. ie then uses the proper encoding and shows the text properly.

Of course that wouldn't work if the text were encoded, for example with:

- UCS-2
- UCS-4
- ISO-10646-UCS-2
- UNICODE-1-1-UTF-8
- UNICODE-2-0-UTF-16
- UNICODE-2-0-UTF-8
- US-ASCII
- ISO-8859-1
- ISO-8859-2
- ISO-8859-3
- ISO-8859-4
- ISO-8859-5
- ISO-8859-6
- ISO-8859-7
- ISO-8859-8
- ISO-8859-9
- WINDOWS-1250
- WINDOWS-1251
- WINDOWS-1252
- WINDOWS-1253
- WINDOWS-1254
- WINDOWS-1255
- WINDOWS-1256
- WINDOWS-1257
- WINDOWS-1258

Answer (score 1):

IE's document supports IPersistMoniker loading too. IE uses [URL monikers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679705(v=VS.85).aspx) for downloading. You can replace the url moniker [created by CreateURLMonikerEx](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/efee3e08-8387-4256-8bea-71e63bfc7526) with your own moniker. A few details about URL moniker's implementation can be find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688738(v=VS.85).aspx). See if you can get IHTTPNegotiate from the binding context when your BindToStroage implemetation is called.

Comment: i don't seen to be able to proceed without knowing what a moniker is, and why i would want one. All the linked resources assume i know what it is, or what it is for.

Comment: See Monikers (COM Fundamentals) at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691261(VS.85).aspx

Comment: What i was getting at is could you post code that solves the problem. i can read all that but i don't appreciate how it can solve my problem.